# Is checking for nullity required in case of a Firestore snapshot?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore, snapshot

I started to rewrite my app using Architecture Components using the instructions in this video:

> [Firebase and Android Jetpack: fit like a glove (Doug Stevenson)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fu2K3lOU3N0#t=6m50s):

```
ref.addSnapshotListener { snapshot, exception ->
    if(snapshot != null) {
        //Do stuff
    }
}
```

I see we can get a `snapshot` or an `exception` and never both. So in this case, is this nullity check really needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to check at least one of the two parameters for null.  If you blindly use one or the other without first checking, you could run into an exception, because you don't know ahead of time which will be non-null.

Comment: I see now. I recognize you, you're the one in that video. Thanks for answering my question. Just voted-up. I cannot mark this answer as accepted. I'll make it after 8 minutes.

Comment: One more small question, so if we check the exception for nullity the snapshot is not necessary to be checked, right?

Comment: As I said, at least one of the two.  You choose which one.